# What's wrong with this import statement?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, es6-modules

I have a default export, "Match" which I'm trying to import into a file called "BrowserAction.js," which is 4 folders away. Both are located in my src folder.

I have this statement in BrowserAction.js:

```
import Match from '../../../discover/Match';
```

BrowserAction.js is in: src-->background

Match.js is in: src-->content-->components-->discover

On a side note, when I import a file from the same background folder as BrowserAction.js into the discover folder, I can use the same number of dots (only changed to `'../../../background/filename'`), and it works.  However, when the file is imported from discover to background, I get a "cannot resolve" error on build.  Can you tell what may be going wrong from this information?

Comment: Is Match the default export or a named export?

Comment: @helloitsjoe It's a default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the import should be following since you only need to go up one directory from `background` (`BrowserAction.js`) to get to `Match.js`

```js
import Match from '../content/components/discover/Match';
```